# How to calculate the current through load resistance in the given diagram?

Tags: transformer, analog, rectifier

[image]

I am here with yet another problem, where I have to find load current, ripple voltage, approx turns ratio? Also, any idea about how can we reduce ripple voltage further?

Attempt: 
This is a step-down transformer and a half-wave rectifier circuit with a capacitor to reduce the ripple voltage at the output.
If the diode is Silicon, I assumed that the voltage drop across it is 0.7V.
Voltage at the junction of diode and capacitor is given 12.5V so 12.5+0.7= 13.2V is what we will receive as output of stepdown transformer.
To calculate approx turns ratio:
Vp/Vs=Np/Ns
so, 240/13.2=18.1818 is the approx turns ratio.
Current through load:
I=V/R
I=12.5/50 = 0.25A

Need guidance in order to figure out ripple voltage and how can we reduce it further?

Comment: This may be helpful: https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/diode/diode_5.html

Comment: The secondary peak voltage will be 13.2 volts. Given that the primary voltage is in RMS volts, you have calculated turns ratio using mismatched values.

Comment: @Andyaka Thank you.
Could you tell me how to calculate the ripple voltage and reduce it further?

Comment: No I can't - this is homework and you need to show some effort.

Comment: you are right. I had calculated Vripple by assuming Vmax=13.2 V
so Imax=13.2/50ohm=0.264A
then as capacitor is connected in the fig I used the capacitor charging formula
I=C* dv/dt
0.264=(1000microF*delta V)/0.02sec.     where f=50hz so T=1/f=0.02Sec
therefore change in the voltage i.e delta V=5.28V
which is the ripple voltage at the output.
I was not sure about the calculation so was hesitant to post.

And as per my reading about half wave rectifier we could reduce ripple by increasing the capacitor value.